# Cycle testimony transparent background in IE not working

Tags: css, internet-explorer, transparency, jquery-cycle

I'm using jquery cycle to display testimonials on my site and want to set the background to transparent. Having changed the CSS the background is transparent in FF, Safari, Chrome and Opera but refuses to be transaprent in IE (specifically 8/9). I've tried all manner of things including using a transparent background png/gif but to no avail.

You can see this on my test site

Does anyone know how to make it transparent? Or another testimony rotator to use instead that will make transparency easier to deal with.

Thanks

Comment: May be something with your PNG fix method. Have you tried to remove the PNG fix and tested in IE8/9?

Comment: Double-check your doc type. The validator gives me an error 'there is no attribute "ONLOAD"' and when I load your page in IE, it defaults to quirks mode.

Comment: Using quirks mode, the only doc type in the software I have to use on this occasion.

Comment: Why can't you change the doctype of the page? I've tested it changing the rendering mode of IE9 from quirks to IE9 and the text block becames transparent.

Comment: Can you please add the original pertinent code into this question so that it will be useful to folks in the future who may have the same problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is IE set the background color to #fff;

If you do view source in IE, you will see:

```
<BLOCKQUOTE style="Z-INDEX: 5; POSITION: absolute; WIDTH: 308px; ZOOM: 1; DISPLAY: block; BACKGROUND: #ffffff; HEIGHT: 150px; TOP: 0px; LEFT: 0px" jQuery15205686771777138462="2" cycleH="150" cycleW="308">
<P>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam. " <CITE>- Martin, NY</CITE></P></BLOCKQUOTE>
```

The fix: add !important to your css background-color rule, to over-write the inline rule.

```
#testimonials1 blockquote {  background-color: transparent !important; }
```

or

```
#testimonials1 blockquote {  background: transparent !important; }
```

Comment: #testimonials1 blockquote {
 width:305px;
 height:150px;
 font-family:Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
 font-size:10pt;
 font-style:italic;
 color:#757575;
 background-color:transparent!important;;
 margin:0px;
}